# How do you apply multiple conditions to a leftjoin on a db_select?

Tags: drupal-7

I'm trying to join the Fivestar ratings for each node so I can sort them by rating. The problem is the Fivestar values I'm querying on are stored in votingapi_cache as multiple rows per node (vote count and the average rating), so I want to do the following:

```
...
LEFT JOIN votingapi_cache fivestar
ON fivestar.entity_id = node.nid
AND fivestar.function = 'average'
```

I've tried the following code, but the problem is the check on "fivestar.function = 'average'" is added to the where clause which eliminates all nodes that have no votes.

```
$query->leftjoin('votingapi_cache', 'fivestar', 'fivestar.entity_id = n.nid');
$query->condition('fivestar.function', 'average', '=');
$query->addField('fivestar', 'value', 'average_rating');
```

---

Ok, the first time I tried this I must have done something wrong, but here's the solution:

```
$query->leftjoin('votingapi_cache', 'fivestar', "fivestar.entity_id = n.nid AND fivestar.function = 'average'");
```

Comment: You should post that as the answer and accept it, then other people visiting the page will find the solution easily :)

Comment: Done and done...I'll mark is as the accepted answer as soon as I can ;)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Ok, the first time I tried this I must have done something wrong, but here's the solution:

```
$query->leftjoin('votingapi_cache', 'fivestar', "fivestar.entity_id = n.nid AND fivestar.function = 'average'");
```

Comment: Just to add to this, I was in the same boat. Going from 'fivestar.entity_id = n.nid AND fivestar.function = "average"' to "fivestar.entity_id = n.nid AND fivestar.function = 'average'" (single quotes to double quotes) was the fix in my case.

Answer (score -1):

Here some multiple join conditions with an IN condition inside the join with implode PHP array to get correct results.

```
$query->leftJoin('element_item','ei','ei.id = ei.id2 AND (ei.param = '.$entity_param.' AND ei.id IN ('.implode(',',$records).'))');
```