# Multiple Condition SQL LeftJoin with Drupal 7

Tags: sql, drupal, drupal-7

This is a continuation of [How do you apply multiple conditions to a leftjoin on a db_select?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8695993/how-do-you-apply-multiple-conditions-to-a-leftjoin-on-a-db-select)

Here's a question: how to you do a leftJoin with a condition where the condition applies to a later table?

i.e. say you have a relationship zoo -> cages -> animals. You want to return a set of all the cages, and info on the animals IF the animals have scales.

```
set 1   | set 2
---------------
cage 1  |  lizard (scales)
cage 1  |  elephant
cage 2  |  bird
cage 3  |  rhino
cage 4  |  lions
```

I'd like to return:

```
set 1   | set 2
---------------
cage 1  |  lizard (scales)
cage 2  |  -empty-
cage 3  |  -empty-
cage 4  |  -empty-
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this would be helpful:

```php
// select from your table
$query = db_select(....);
....

$query->condition('set2.animal_name', db_like('scales'), 'LIKE');
$query->groupBy('set1.cage_field');

// continue query
....
```

Where `set2` is you table with animals and `animal_name` is you field with names.

But this query will return to you the following

```
set 1   | set 2
---------------
cage 1  |  lizard (scales)
```